# Transfer Learning from Gradient Boosting to Neural Network

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, transfer-learning

I am working on a project that that is meant to predict student's results as early in the school term as possible, using given data, like their class tests and practicals. I am required to train a model to predict the weaker students as soon as possible (Basically for the teacher to give them more attention). I am working on this project as my Final year project, and wanted to impress my lecturers too, so I went to reaearch a bit about the available models, and I came across Transfer learning. I wanted to use that as part of my project, in order to improve the effectiveness (accuracy of predicting the final grade of a student) of any model I were to use. I ended up using Gradient Boosting (I did mse and r^2 tests, and Gradient Boosting resulted with the a consistent higher r^2 value compared to random tree, ElasticNet, Lasso, Ridge). I cleaned my sample data (a csv that contains students' results, which I can train and verify), and when I tested out my code (Just Gradient boosting, It resulted in a accuracy value just shy of 70%, which might not that effective [for instance, a student with a GPA of 1.0 in the csv was predicted to be 3.9, which is way off]). Hence I wanted to combine neural network on top of gradient boosting, to improve the accuracy. But while doing so, I am faced with a shape problem.

```
ValueError: Layer dense_6 weight shape (39, 39) is not compatible with provided weight shape (39,).
```

Here is my code with Just Gradient Boosting (works fine):

```
p1Scores = []
p2Scores = []
p3Scores = []
p4Scores = []
fScores = []
df = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Project AIML/student results 2.csv")
for col in df.columns:
  if(("P1" in col or "PT1" in col) and not 'T_' in col):
    p1Scores.append(col)
  if(("P2" in col or "PT2" in col) and not 'T_' in col):
    p2Scores.append(col)
  if(("P3" in col or "PT3" in col) and not 'T_' in col):
    p3Scores.append(col)
  if(("P4" in col or "PT4" in col) and not 'T_' in col):
    p4Scores.append(col)
  if(("PT1" in col or "PT2" in col or "PT3" in col or "PT4" in col or "Final" in col) and not 'T_' in col):
    fScores.append(col)

X = pd.concat([df[p1Scores].dropna(), df[p2Scores].dropna(),df[p3Scores].dropna(),df[p4Scores].dropna()], axis=1)
# X = df[p1Scores].dropna()
y = df["Final Grade"].dropna()

# Find the indices of y that are not in X
diff_indices = X.index.difference(y.index)

# Drop the rows in X that are not in y
X = X.drop(diff_indices)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

gb = GradientBoostingRegressor()
search_spaces = {
    'learning_rate': (0.01, 1.0, 'log-uniform'),
    'max_depth': (1, 25),
    'min_samples_split': (2, 25),
    'min_samples_leaf': (1, 20),
    'subsample': (0.01, 1.0, 'uniform'),
    'max_features': (0.01, 1.0, 'uniform')
}

optimizer = BayesSearchCV(gb, search_spaces, n_iter=10, cv=5)
optimizer.fit(X, y)

best_gb = optimizer.best_estimator_
y_pred = best_gb.predict(X_test)
print("Accuracy :", r2_score(y_test, best_gb.predict(X_test)) * 100, "%")

# df = pd.DataFrame({'y': y_test, 'y_pred': y_pred})
# df = df[df['y'] < 3.0]
# print(df)
# Accuracy : 65.63926875890978 %
```

I also did another code for just neural network (works fine too):

```
p1Scores = []
p2Scores = []
p3Scores = []
p4Scores = []
fScores = []
df = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Project AIML/student results 2.csv")
for col in df.columns:
  if(("P1" in col or "PT1" in col) and not 'T_' in col):
    p1Scores.append(col)
  if(("P2" in col or "PT2" in col) and not 'T_' in col):
    p2Scores.append(col)
  if(("P3" in col or "PT3" in col) and not 'T_' in col):
    p3Scores.append(col)
  if(("P4" in col or "PT4" in col) and not 'T_' in col):
    p4Scores.append(col)
  if(("PT1" in col or "PT2" in col or "PT3" in col or "PT4" in col or "Final" in col) and not 'T_' in col):
    fScores.append(col)

X = pd.concat([df[p1Scores].dropna(), df[p2Scores].dropna(),df[p3Scores].dropna(),df[p4Scores].dropna()], axis=1)
# X = df[p1Scores].dropna()
y = df["Final Grade"].dropna()

# Find the indices of y that are not in X
diff_indices = X.index.difference(y.index)

# Drop the rows in X that are not in y
X = X.drop(diff_indices)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

# Scale the data
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

# Create the neural network
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(X_train.shape[1], input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=32, verbose=0)

# Make predictions
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

# Calculate accuracy
accuracy = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
print("Accuracy :", accuracy * 100, "%")
# Output:
# 7/7 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
# Accuracy : 51.52249363734857 %
```

But when I am attempting to do Transfer learning I am getting shape error:

```
p1Scores = []
p2Scores = []
p3Scores = []
p4Scores = []
fScores = []
df = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Project AIML/student results 2.csv")
for col in df.columns:
  if(("P1" in col or "PT1" in col) and not 'T_' in col):
    p1Scores.append(col)
  if(("P2" in col or "PT2" in col) and not 'T_' in col):
    p2Scores.append(col)
  if(("P3" in col or "PT3" in col) and not 'T_' in col):
    p3Scores.append(col)
  if(("P4" in col or "PT4" in col) and not 'T_' in col):
    p4Scores.append(col)
  if(("PT1" in col or "PT2" in col or "PT3" in col or "PT4" in col or "Final" in col) and not 'T_' in col):
    fScores.append(col)

X = pd.concat([df[p1Scores].dropna(), df[p2Scores].dropna(),df[p3Scores].dropna(),df[p4Scores].dropna()], axis=1)
# X = df[p1Scores].dropna()
y = df["Final Grade"].dropna()

# Find the indices of y that are not in X
diff_indices = X.index.difference(y.index)

# Drop the rows in X that are not in y
X = X.drop(diff_indices)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

gb = GradientBoostingRegressor()
search_spaces = {
    'learning_rate': (0.01, 1.0, 'log-uniform'),
    'max_depth': (1, 25),
    'min_samples_split': (2, 25),
    'min_samples_leaf': (1, 20),
    'subsample': (0.01, 1.0, 'uniform'),
    'max_features': (0.01, 1.0, 'uniform')
}

optimizer = BayesSearchCV(gb, search_spaces, n_iter=10, cv=5)
optimizer.fit(X, y)

best_gb = optimizer.best_estimator_
y_pred = best_gb.predict(X_test)
print("Accuracy :", r2_score(y_test, best_gb.predict(X_test)) * 100, "%")

# df = pd.DataFrame({'y': y_test, 'y_pred': y_pred})
# df = df[df['y'] < 3.0]
# print(df)

# get the feature importances from the gradient boosting model
feature_importances = best_gb.feature_importances_

# print(feature_importances.shape)
# print(X_train.shape[1])

# create a neural network with the same input shape as the gradient boosting model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
# set the neural network's weights to the feature importances of the gradient boosting model
model.layers[0].set_weights([feature_importances, np.zeros(64)])

# train the neural network
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=64)

# evaluate the neural network's performance
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print("Accuracy :", r2_score(y_test, y_pred) * 100, "%")


####################################################################################
Terminal Output Error
____________________________________________________________________________________
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-fd978c02a73d> in <module>
     64 model.add(Dense(1))
     65 # set the neural network's weights to the feature importances of the gradient boosting model
---> 66 model.layers[0].set_weights([feature_importances, np.zeros(64)])
     67 
     68 # train the neural network

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in set_weights(self, weights)
   1641         ref_shape = param.shape
   1642         if not ref_shape.is_compatible_with(weight_shape):
-> 1643           raise ValueError(
   1644               f'Layer {self.name} weight shape {ref_shape} '
   1645               'is not compatible with provided weight '

ValueError: Layer dense_6 weight shape (39, 39) is not compatible with provided weight shape (39,).
####################################################################################
```

What am I missing in the transfer learning? I got check the sizes but they match (39,39)

Additional Note: If you are willing, could someone recommend me any suggestions or recommendations to improve this project <3 It will be really helpful for the future students who are really struggling if it actually works :)

Comment: In transfer learning you want a parent model to give his knowledge to a child model, this knowledge can be a feature vector. Here you are using the GB model as the parent model and you do use his 'feature importance' to set weights of the NNet. It doesn't really make sense to me and that's what is the error about. IMO you should think about first feeding the NNet to get a vector of features and pass them to the GB model. You can take a look there https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/#the-typical-transferlearning-workflow

Comment: I partially agree with @imM4TT but using feature weights learnt by gradient boosting can also be done. In case of a dense layer, each unit/neuron will have a weight for each input, but since gradient boosting only gives 1 set of these, best you can do is initialize each neuron with these same weights which is redundant. Your error is most likely  because of input feature importance shape not fitting number of neurons. (Is (39, 39) shape required for this model (with 64 neurons) or was it from some iteration of code)